# SQL Server trigger doesn't work for insert, but works for update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a SQL Server trigger that doesn't work `for` or `after` `insert`, but it works `for update`. The data is imported from a CSV file, and I know for sure the records are being inserted because the record count in the SQL Server table goes up.

What could cause this situation to occur?

Here is my trigger. A high level description is: a `jobs` record can be related to multiple `job_budgets` records, and are matched by `job_no`. `job_budgets` has some costs that I want to sum up and put into a field in `jobs`.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MC_tu_jobs_by_job_budgets] 
ON [dbo].[job_budgets]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    if update(orig_est_dollars)
    begin
        update dbo.jobs
        set jobs.original_cost = (select sum(job_budgets.orig_est_dollars) 
                                  from job_budgets 
                                  where job_budgets.job_no = i.job_no 
                                    and job_budgets.company_no = i.company_no)
        from inserted as i
        inner join dbo.[jobs] on dbo.[jobs].job_no = i.job_no 
                              and dbo.[jobs].company_no = i.company_no
    end
end
```

Comment: The imported records from CSV file are inserted into [job_budgets] table. Just confirming as it not evident from the question. It will be great if you can share the schema of both the tables.

Comment: Your trigger definition looks perfectly alright. I was able to create all the db objects including the trigger and it is working fine on my box for both update and delete operation. Are you sure insertion from CSV to job_budgets table is really happening? What is the mechanism/tool which is reading data from CSV file and dumping into database table?

Comment: When you're **inserting** new data - there's no previous data to compare to, so that `if update(orig_est_dollars)` will always be **false** .... I'd recommend to write **separate** triggers for the `INSERT` and the `UPDATE` case to avoid messy if/then/else code inside your trigger...

Comment: @RBT: the import creates one record for the [jobs] table and multiple records for the [job_budgets] table. When I run a record count before and after the import for [job_budgets], it goes up. I don't know the mechanism since we bought the software. But I have access to the database so I am trying to do things here that the software lacks.

@marc_s: I commented out the `if update(orig_est_dollars)` lines and it still does not work `for insert`.

Comment: still can you give it a shot by writing two separate triggers for insert and update as suggested by @marc_s just to rule out that case.